# spring boot HttpServletRequest getRemoteAddr() always returns 33.3.2.22

Tags: spring, servlets, spring-boot, ip

I have a spring boot data rest api. Im trying to get the ip address of a request. Im injecting a HttpServletRequest bean into my MediaEventHandler that i created to handle before and after create events. in the before create method i call httpRequestServlet.getRemoteAddr().

Now when I persist a Media entity it seems to populate the ip obtained from my call to getRemoteAddr(). However, the ip address is always 33.3.2.22 whether I run the app on my local machine or on aws.

Any ideas why this would be?

Answer (score 3):

You are probably getting the IP of your default gateway. Take a look at this:  https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-client-ip-address-in-java/

```
//is client behind something? 
String ipAddress = request.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR"); 
if (ipAddress == null) {     
    ipAddress = request.getRemoteAddr(); 
}
```

There are still no guarantee you'll get the true client IP, but I believe this is the best you can do.

Comment: Hi. Yes the call to httpRequestServlet.getRemoteAddr() is made in the api (on the server). I know what you're saying about getting the same IP because im using the same client, however....33.3.2.22 is definately not the IP of my client. As far as i can tell, I am getting what I wanted, except the IP  is somehow showing as 33.3.2.22 instead of my ACTUAL IP. Any ideas why it would be different?

Comment: Thankyou. This is an area of computing where my knowledge is a bit weak; i wouldnt have guessed this. I'm at work, but when i return home I'll confirm to you whether this is the case. Thanks! :)